# Business Objects User Input with Prompts

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I am trying to create the following logic on a Business Intelligence Report (Business Objects):

The requirement is an Initial Prompt in which a user can enter "A" or "M" which "A" stands for Auto and "M" for manual. Based on the user Input,

- if "A" is chosen the report will refresh with current year.
- If "M" is chosen then the report will provide another Prompt asking the user to select which year he wants.

What i have tried so far is the Cascade Prompt, but in the current situation is not feasible.
Is it posible to implement this kind of logic in SAP BO Report Or create a prompt that is not mapped to a dimension Object?

Just to mention i am using Universe Design Tool version 4.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly achieve your objective by creating a filter with prompt in the Business Layer of your universe, but it is going to function a little differently that you are describing. The idea is you prompt for the number of years to go back. So "0" would be the current year, "-1" would be the previous year, "1" would be the next year, and so on.

[image]

This is SQL Server T-SQL syntax so you would need adjust the code to fit whatever database your universe is based upon if it is not SQL Server. Of course, you would need to replace my table and date column with yours.

> CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(YEAR, @Prompt('Number of
> years:','N',,Mono,Free,Not_Persistent,,User:0), GETDATE())) = [Your
> table and column goes here]

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I was able to find solution to the requirement.  The solution is similar to yours i just adjust the solution according to the Database structure.